# Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'

Tags: typescript

I'm learning Typescript from the [excellent docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html), and while practicing [*Mapped Types*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#further-exploration), I'm running into this error.

I know why this error is occuring (explained below) but since I'm new to TS, I don't know the recommended way of fixing it.

The code is below (and here's [the link to the code playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECUFMAcCdIM6QHYBcGgQYwBaQLYCGoA9gGajEAiARqKoTQDaQBQqAntJKAKpKxQAXlABvVqFABLACYAuUMgCu+GpFgBuSaBCh8UgOY5UoNZSWoS05Fnj4UqSDNMdQVAEITFhewoSpYKWQDLV0sEjRCIIxHAA9UJUImb3tQGUIGVgBfDVZWXQBZQmUk0AB3ElgAawA6N0gyIJ5iTm56HAzQeDhEBwxsPCJSCgAifnURymRnQhlnBBJU+wZ0zNaeDwAxKUgmGQwRcUlZBVFQMkqiVAURoNsCByCDSZyvZB9IU-ouT8wAp600CkUgUASUPFer3YP1AAFF4rBCFhUAAFACSaIAPAAVH4APmEYi8AG0UbASNxYJxrKAqpAOORQLjuABdBTMyCk8mUzgs0CQeIofZiUBAkH0WDg0BZUAAfglUoUZCSSFyUPWoAA8jQAFaQZEIABykCcTwA4lQUeAqLtIKgpBFCfCAkjURjMVsdnsEHjcvkwEUSskKtU6gBheAZHgkXX6kyM7V6g3G03BC1Wm0se2O9asLNpW3Z5BFarqBAKRNxo0mmTmy3WwsO5CEo7SeTnFWQAA0bw+oMlbChZCUNiLoA60xY6YbWabUAAjuD-AAKJQCBTjWBdguziIlumwcta2PJmt1jONiIASiJknzWBYxScm4UKMIVKkSUxm4JhyhkguQRl3zRpdmcIJQDXdQb1bY4KGXABCGRL2Ld8DwQYlQL2SgMDpBkKE3FkYK8bRQAfSAnxkTdMK9GZcPpRlCMJKDYBosCcNpBiCIEFlclIrIvAErxwmQBYWBqJgSAMZdyMozcry0HQwDJIJ0C+E5QAARmlbI8nzFiWy8DTNJ7SR3l8UARgAKRIHBmyoEhIBGHsoQnGQp3rTM7TnSBF0QVBVwEbdkN3VDS0PBTJF0M5jOlIA)):

```
// Represents schema of a Db table
type User = {
  id: number;   // might be auto incremented by DB
  name: string; // contains textual name data
};

// Manual work. Define a type that represents schema of "User" and add some metadata
type DBFields = {
  id: { format: "incrementing" };
  name: { type: string; pii: true };
};

type ExtractPII<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]: Type[Property] extends { pii: true } ? true : false;
};

type ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion = ExtractPII<DBFields>;

// Manual work. Create object of ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion type
let deletionMarkers: ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion = {
  id: false,
  name: true
};

function handleGDPRDeletionRequest(user: User, deletionMarkers: ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion) {
  let cleanedUser: Partial<User> = {};

  for (const field of Object.keys(user)) {
    if (!deletionMarkers[field as keyof User]) {
      cleanedUser[field as keyof User] = user[field as keyof User];
    }
  }

  console.log(cleanedUser);  // Prints: { id: 1 }
}

let user = {
  id: 1,
  name: "John Doe",
};

handleGDPRDeletionRequest(user, deletionMarkers);  // { id: 1 }
```

** **Please correct me if this explanation is not accurate** **

The error is happening at line

```
cleanedUser[field as keyof User] = user[field as keyof User];
```

because `cleanedUser` is declared as a `Partial<User>`. `Partial<User>` means that all properties of `User` are optional and can potentially be `undefined`.

And when we try to assign `user[field as keyof User]`, which can be a `string` or `number` to these potentially `undefined` properties, TypeScript throws this error.

---

I tried asking ChatGPT and BingAI and they suggest some hacky solution like declaring `cleanedUser` as `any` which I don't want to do.

So I'm turning to SO for a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR answer

Change the function to

```
function handleGDPRDeletionRequest(user: User, deletionMarkers: ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion) {

  const cleanedUser: Partial<User> = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(user).filter(([userKey]) => !deletionMarkers[userKey as keyof User])
  );

  console.log(cleanedUser);  // Prints: { id: 1 }
}
```

#### Why does it solve the problem?

Rather than attempting an assignment that TypeScript flags as incompatible, it constructs a clean, new object that TypeScript can confidently infer types for.

To fully understand this, read the explanation sections below.

---

### Explanation of Issue

The error is happening at line

```
cleanedUser[field as keyof User] = user[field as keyof User];
```

During this assignment, TS has no way to understand that `cleanedUser[field]` and `user[field]` correspond to the *same*, *specific* data type from one specific key.

So, TS will only allow values that are compatible with *all* possible types of keys of `cleanedUser`.

Lets quickly recall the types of `cleanedUser` and `user`

[image]
 
  [image]

The all possible types of keys of `cleanedUser` are

1. `number | undefined`
2. `string | undefined`

Type that is compatible with both of the above types is `undefined`. This is what TS allows here.

Hence the error:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

#### Why does the error have 2 lines?

Line 1 shows the error, with the full types included. In line 2, it picks `string`, only because it is the first constituent of the union type, to highlight a more specific example of one particular part of the overall type `string | number` that is incompatible with the left-hand side (`undefined`).

In this case, the second line does not really provide any extra info, and it might even be a little misleading, because both `string` and `number` are incompatible with `undefined` on the left-hand side — `string` is not the only problem. However, in many other TypeScript errors, it can be very helpful for TypeScript to slowly break down big types to highlight the incompatible parts.

---

### Explanation of Solution

```
  const cleanedUser: Partial<User> = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(user).filter(([userKey]) => !deletionMarkers[userKey as keyof User])
  );
```

- `Object.entries(user)`: This turns the `user` object into an array of `[key, value]` tuples. It's equivalent to `[['id', 1], ['name', 'John Doe']]`.
- `.filter(([userKey]) => !deletionMarkers[userKey as keyof User])`: This applies the filter method from the Array prototype, which iterates over every element of the array and includes only those elements for which the provided callback function returns true.
  `[userKey]` [destructures](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-tuple-destructuring-works-in-typescript/) the tuple passed to it and grabs the first element from each [key, value] tuple.
- `Object.fromEntries(...)`: This function is essentially the reverse of `Object.entries(...)`. It receives an iterable (for instance, an array) of entries, where each entry is an array with a key-value pair, and transforms it back into an object. So, `Object.fromEntries([['id', 1]])` results in `{ id: 1 }`.

---

### [Reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/18mf4v6/comment/ke3utvk/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have to resort to creating a generic function for things like this. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECUFMAcCdIM6QHYBcGgQYwBaQLYCGoA9gGajEAiARqKoTQDaQBQqAntJKAKpKxQAXlABvVqFABLACYAuUMgCu+GpFgBuSaBCh8UgOY5UoNZSWoS05Fnj4UqSDNMdQVAEITFhewoSpYKWQDLV0sEjRCIIxHAA9UJUImb3tQGUIGVgBfDVZWXQBZQmUk0AB3ElgAawA6N0gyIJ5iTm56HAzQeDhEBwxsPCJSCgAifnURymRnQhlnBBJU+wZ0zNaeDwAxKUgmGQwRcUlZBVFQMkqiVAURoNsCByCDSZyvZB9IU-ouT8wAp600CkUgUASUPFer3YP1AAFF4rBCFhUAAFACSaIAPAAVH4APmEYi8AG0UbASNxYJxrKAqpAOORQLjuABdBTMyCk8mUzgs0CQeIofZiUBAkH0WDg0BZUAAfglUoUZCSSFyUPWoAA8jQAFaQZEIABykCcTwA4lQUeAqLtIKgpBFCfCAkjURjMVsdnsEHjcvkwEUSskKtU6gBheAZHgkXX6kyM7V6g3G03BC1Wm0se2O9asLNpW3Z5BFarqBAKRNxo0mmTmy3WwsO5CEo7SeTnFWQAA0bw+oMlbChZCUNiLoA60xY6YbWabUAAjuD-AAKJQCBTjWBdguziIlumwcta2PJmt1jONiIASiJknzWBYxScm4UKMIVKkSUxm4JhyhkguQRl3CZB-HOL1nATE9UBqOkOAQVcBCvG9W0kcJoA4NEyENEhUEzO0nGXRpdhmDA4MZTdtxkS9i3fA8EG3Nd1G3B9ICfGRNyvXJJCyPI0IiBYWBqJgSAMYDH2QZ8kK0HQwDJIJ0C+E5QAARmlbI8mHUcm1AdDMOw3D8McGRMQAaX5QVpjI+kKIEPFlzghRTKomj9zLCtoOrVMDGnIym0Y9c+AEFiJKk9RX3fe0vx-FCvCkChlwAQmo3daNLQ9iTgllYu0XTQo4gRMvpPkRCY2Aio4FluPU3i8ztUAypbOL2xUntJHeXxQBGAApEgcGbKgSEgEYeyhCcZCnes-IiBcl1QRDmJ3O0mzcw8uMkXQzmUtSsiAA):

```js
// Represents schema of a Db table
type User = {
  id: number;   // might be auto incremented by DB
  name: string; // contains textual name data
};

// Manual work. Define a type that represents schema of "User" and add some metadata
type DBFields = {
  id: { format: "incrementing" };
  name: { type: string; pii: true };
};

type ExtractPII<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]: Type[Property] extends { pii: true } ? true : false;
};

type ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion = ExtractPII<DBFields>;

// Manual work. Create object of ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion type
let deletionMarkers: ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion = {
  id: false,
  name: true
};

function handleGDPRDeletionRequest(user: User, deletionMarkers: ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion) {
  let cleanedUser: Partial<User> = {};

  for (const field of Object.keys(user)) {
    copyIfNotDeleted(field as keyof User, deletionMarkers, user, cleanedUser);
  }

  console.log(cleanedUser);  // Prints: { id: 1 }
}

function copyIfNotDeleted<K extends keyof User>(key: K, deletionMarkers: ObjectsNeedingGDPRDeletion, user: User, cleanedUser: Partial<User>) {
  if (!deletionMarkers[key]) {
    cleanedUser[key] = user[key];
  }
}

let user = {
  id: 1,
  name: "John Doe",
};

handleGDPRDeletionRequest(user, deletionMarkers);  // { id: 1 }
```

As I understand it, the reason this works is because there's a difference between a variable having the type `keyof User` which means *any key of User* versus having a type `K` that *extends* `keyof User`, which means it's a *subset* of this set of keys, for example a single key. Thus, for the expression under question:

```js
cleanedUser[field as keyof User] = user[field as keyof User];
```

...the type of `user[field as keyof User]` is `number | string` because that's the union of all possible property value types that can come from a key of `User`. If `field` could somehow be of a *dynamic* type that's a subset of `keyof User` then the type of `user[field]` would be the type for that specific field. The only way I've found to get TypeScript to allow for a variable to be of a varying type is through generics. A variable can't hold different types within iterations of a loop, but it can through different function invokes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain why moving the copying logic into a new function solved this issue? Does the copy logic not work inside the `for` loop of `handleGDPRDeletionRequest ` function?

Comment: I've added more details to the answer. In short, it's a TypeScript limitation, one I hope they fix in the future, because a variable holding different types within loop iterations would be _super_ powerful.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. Upvoted. As for accepting the answer, I'll accept the other one (that I wrote ) with a lot of explanation of issue and solution. Thank you again!